# Get polygons from edges in OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I have an image I want to extract lines from (a vascular network), using the Hough line algorithm. First I preprocess the image, then use Canny edge detection to generate the binary image.

[image]

I want to get a polygon/an array of joined line segments representing the shape of the vascular network. However applying the Hough line transform directly on this image yields mediocre results, partly because edge detection means each vessel is represented by two lines on each side, instead of a single line.

I'm new to OpenCV and image processing in general, so I'm probably going about this the wrong way. Any suggestions, or any recommended literature?

Comment: Perhaps in order to get things in the form of a single line you could try using an [erosion](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html#erosion)?

Comment: The double line is an artifact created by canny if applied to s thin line. Try uploading your original image to better understand the problem

Comment: Dilate the contour once. Doing so would merge the 2 parallel lines into one, then you can use Hough

Answer (score 2):

I suggest not using Canny edge detection.

Instead, first use a binary threshold to get a binary image of the vascular network (see http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html#gsc.tab=0 for applying a binary threshold). Then, pixels that are "on" should be points inside the network and those that are "off" should be outside.

Then use the findContours method:

http://opencvexamples.blogspot.com/2013/09/find-contour.html

This method gives you an array of contours, each of which is a list of points. A list of points will represent the list of line segments you are looking for (it will represent a contour, and if you are lucky it might be a polygon!).

Answer (score 1):

Hough may not be the best tool for this job.  Hough will give you straight lines or other geometric shapes.  It is not designed to follow a detailed pattern like this.

Given the image, I would read research papers which already solve this.  Here are a few examples from a search on Google Scholar.  If they don't work for you, look up the citations as they should lead you down other paths.

- https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=retina+computer+vision+vascular
- http://ijesat.org/Volumes/2012_Vol_02_Iss_04/IJESAT_2012_02_04_25.pdf
- http://www.vision.cs.rpiscrews.us/publications/pdfs/shen_itbm_submitted.pdf